# Unable to delete a Chef role with "." in its name

Tags: chef-infra, roles, knife, cookbook

I had uploaded a wrong role (rrb_v10.0.0.1) by mistake to Chef Server.

```
knife role list
rrb_v10.0.0.1
rrb_v10
```

When I try to delete this role, I get the following error

```
knife role delete rrb_v10.0.0.1
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option name's value rrb_v10.0.0.1 does not match regular expression /^[\-[:alnum:]_]+$/
```

I tried to log in to Chef Manage console but its unable to show any role in the console UI. I also tried to prefix every dot with \ but that didn't work.
Please provide your advise on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this:

`knife exec -E 'api.delete("/roles/rrb_v10.0.0.1")'`

Will bypass all the client-side validations.

Comment: knife exec -E 'api.delete("/roles/rrb_v10.0.0.1")'
    ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option name's value rrb_v10.0.0.1 does not match regular expression /^[\-[:alnum:]_]+$/

Comment: I made some changes to the single and double quotes and it worked!! Thanks!  knife exec -E "api.delete('/roles/rrb_v10.0.0.1_hcp_v4.json')"

Comment: It works if you swap the single and double quotes just like sourav de said.